# How to empty Cloudflare cache automatically only on pages where new content/ code appears

Tags: cloudflare

We have a blog, and continually publish new articles or change code. The new posts will appear on several overview pages on our website.

Currently, new content is not automatically available because the old cache is visible and doesn't empty automatically.

We want o to avoid continually manually having to empty cache on all overview pages or delete all cache on the entire website.

**Question:**

Are there settings in Cloudflare that cache automatically empties on only pages where content/ code updates are detected?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. The easiest is to lower your cache time to something where you have a balance between how frequently content is updated vs cache efficiency.

If you want to have a long cache time, but automatically clear the cache for a URL when an update occurs, you would have to notify Cloudflare of this change. You can do this in an automated way, using their API -

https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url

There may be pre-built tools to help with this, depending on what CMS you are using for your blog. For example, Wordpress has a plugin -

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002708027-Cloudflare-WordPress-Plugin-Automatic-Cache-Management-